# Is a class by default public, private or internal

Tags: class, swift

When i declare a class:

```
class foo {
    //code goes here
}
```

Is the class standard `public`, `private` or `internal`?
I was wondering about this and wasn't able to find any information about it.

Comment: From the documentation, "Default Access Levels

All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions, as described later in this chapter) have a default access level of internal if you do not specify an explicit access level yourself. As a result, in many cases you do not need to specify an explicit access level in your code."

Comment: I'm guessing it's public since you can instantiate and access it in global context.

Comment: @cyrbil By default, you can only instantiate and access the class within the same module.

Comment: .NET defaults a class to private so I was going to guess that Swift worked the same way.  From what I have seen I am pretty sure it defaults to internal though.  Either internal or private make sense as a default; I would say that public does NOT make sense as a default though...

Comment: Yeah, just saw it.
To complete Richard's answer here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) :

> All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions, as
>   described later in this chapter) have a default access level of
>   internal if you do not specify an explicit access level yourself. As a
>   result, in many cases you do not need to specify an explicit access
>   level in your code

it is internal.